# Javascript - Increasing value by keypress, only once

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-physics, keypress, onkeypress

im trying to get the value of a variable that i have to increase by 5 each time that the up key is pressed.

Currently i have the variable increasing upon keypress etc but the main problem i have is that from one keypress, the value will continue rise. For example, value would start at 5, upon **one** keypress would continue to rise by 5 each time and would stop just after 600. Whereas i want it to **start at 5 then upon each keypress go to 10,15,20....**

Here's the code i have, i'd be grateful for the help on where im going wrong etc

```
var projectoryHeight = 5;

function setHeight()
{
    projectoryHeight = projectoryHeight + 5;
};

if (keyCode == 38)
{
    setHeight();
    console.log(projectoryHeight);
};
```

The code that relates to keycode for the up key being placed, is inside a rendering function, for use with requestAnimationFrame(). I feel like this may be what is causing the issue of it continuing to count however I have tried moving it outside of this function and nothing happens.

Javascript being used alongside **THREE.js & Physi.js**

More code to help with problem:

```
var render = function() {
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            scene.simulate();

            let keyFlag = false;

            // Update the title page shape rotations
            sphere.rotation.y += 0.06;
            sphere.rotation.x += 0.10;
            sphere.rotation.z += 0.06;



            document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
                if(e.code == 'KeyW'){
                $(title).hide();
                    $(keyTitle).hide();
                    scene.remove(sphere);
                    sphere.geometry.dispose();
                    sphere.material.dispose();

                    //add all the game functions here
                    scene.add(cube);
                    scene.add(firingBall);
                    scene.add(struct1);
                    scene.add(struct2);
                    scene.add(struct3);
                    scene.add(struct4);
                    scene.add(struct5);
                    scene.add(struct6);
                    scene.simulate();
                }
            });   

            document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
                if(e.code == 'Space'){
                firingBall.setLinearVelocity(new THREE.Vector3(speedOfBall, projectoryHeight, 0));
                }                
            });

            document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
                if(e.code == 'ArrowUp'){
                if (!keyFlag) {
                        keyFlag = true;
                        projectoryHeight = projectoryHeight + 5;
                        console.log(projectoryHeight);
                    }
                }                
            });

             document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
                if(e.code == 'ArrowDown'){
                if (!keyFlag) {
                        keyFlag = true;
                        projectoryHeight = projectoryHeight - 5;
                        console.log(projectoryHeight);
                    }
                }                
            });

               document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
                if(e.code == 'ArrowUp'){
                if (keyFlag){
                    console.log("stopped");
                    keyFlag = false;
                }
                }
            });

            document.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
                if(e.code == 'ArrowDown'){
                if (keyFlag){
                    console.log("stopped");
                    keyFlag = false;
                }
                }
            });


            renderer.autoClear = false;
            renderer.clear();
            renderer.render(backgroundScene, backgroundCamera);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };
```

This is the function where keypresses etc are used, inside the render function. Also starts the animation frames and game physics.

This function is then called directly after it is declared

Thanks

Comment: Please create a minimal example demonstrating your issue. I have created a small [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j2z1vgxm/4/) showing your code is working.

Comment: What event are you using to trigger `setHeight()`?

Comment: hi, @adriani6 i have tried to create a jsfiddle however i cannot get it to produce the problem related.

Comment: @Jpec07 the function is being used inside a Three.js vector which is being used for velocity of an object, setHeight is then being used to set the height of trajectory

Comment: I will update the question with more info

Comment: you may want to check for the keyup event as well so that each individual keydown/keyup event is counted as a single keypress. Also, it sounds like your code is running continually, like the vector function it is wrapped in is always running so a keydown event causes it to trigger multiple times...

Comment: hi, added a key up event however nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a flag that tells you whether or not a key is being held down. To do this in simple form, you can use the `keydown` event in conjunction with the `keyup` event. In the following code the key can be held down but it only performs an action once based on the flag.

```
i.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (!keyflag) console.log(e.key);
  keyflag = true;
});

i.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (keyflag) console.log("released!");
  keyflag = false;
});
```

```js
let i = document.querySelector("input"),
  keyflag = false;

i.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  if (!keyflag) console.log(e.key);
  else e.preventDefault();
  keyflag = true;
});

i.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  if (keyflag) console.log("released!");
  else e.preventDefault();
  keyflag = false;
});
```

```html
<input>
```

**Note** inside the snippet I use `e.preventDefault()` to stop letters appearing in the input box. My intention was only that this would make it easier to see.

Comment: hi, ive added a key up event and nothing has changed?

Comment: @NeilHouston did you change your event to keydown and add a flag?

Comment: Did you add the keyflag, though? That's the important part. The `keydown` event will trigger any time the JavaScript loop picks up that the key is pressed. Depending on your hardware, the loop could run a few dozen times in the milliseconds it takes for the key to be pressed. The keyflag is what registers it as a single event, rather than several different events.

Comment: yep added the keyflag. Also have eventlisteners for both key down and key up

Comment: Can you edit your first post to include the event listener logic in your JavaScript? That's where the error is, we're pretty sure, but we can't know 100% until we can see it.

Comment: ive already edited my code to use the style which @zfrisch is using, nothing changed

Comment: @NeilHouston I feel like I'm giving you an answer to your question, and I'd be happy to show you how you can implement it within your code, but you're going to have to provide more of your code for me, or anyone, to do that.

Comment: @zfrisch added more of the code, hope that can help

Comment: @NeilHouston I'll take a look at it closer in a while, but my first test would be to take keyflag and make it global. If it's rendering over and over it's constantly going to be set to false.

Comment: @zfrisch making the variable global did the trick, thank you so much!